# Append emberjs component to dom in route

Tags: dom, ember.js

I'm dynamically creating an ember component with an ember route and need to append this component into the DOM. I do so like this:

```
createwidget : function (row, column, value, htmlElement) {
                var componentObj = {};
                componentObj.props = {
                                        id: 'selectid', 
                                        content: $this.codes, 
                                        optionValuePath: 'code', 
                                        optionLabelPath: 'value', 
                                        selectedValue: '', 
                                        name: 'selectInputName', 
                                        selectedLabel: '', 
                                        dropdownLabel: 'selectLabel', 
                                        placeholder: 'selectPlaceholder'
                                    };
                componentObj.name = 'jpma-select';
                componentObj.type = 'component';
                var component = $this._createComponent(componentObj);
                component.appendTo($(htmlElement));
            }
```

createwidget is function that comes from the jqxgrid widget. It allows you to dynamically create elements and add them to a grid cell. _createComponent is one of our custom methods that creates a custom ember component, in this case a select. I get the error:
"Assertion Failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead."

If I wrap the component as a jQuery object, like this:
$(component).appendTo($(htmlElement));

I get this error:
"jpma-analytics-tracker.js:154 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined(…)"

So what gives? What can I do to make this work?
Thanks

Comment: This is either brilliant or totally insane. I can't tell. How does does this work with ember's component lifecycle hooks?

Comment: In short: this won't work. I suggest using the `each` and `component` helpers in concert.

Comment: I suspect that this won't work either, or is just not a good idea, but its been given to me as requirement, but I think I'll just push back a little harder.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe Javascript or jQuery way. Maybe you'll achive to make it work but IMO that is not the way Ember does.

Use [component helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component) to create dynamic components.

And my personal experience, if you need a component to modify, do it in a component (perhaps a wrapper/outer component), not in a route.